# Python Pandas CSV - IndexError with axis and size

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I keep getting this error when trying to add an empty column in an imported CSV.

"IndexError: index 27 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25"

The original CSV spans A-Z (0-25 columns) then AA, AB, AC, AD (26, 27, 28, 29).

[OriginalCSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o21Xl.png)

The csv with the error currently stretches A-Z but the error occurs when trying to add the column after then - in this case AA. I guess that would be 26.

[Problem CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNUTw.png)

Here is the code:

````
```
#import CSV to dataframe
orders = pd.read_csv("Orders.csv", header=None)

#copy columns needed from order to ordersNewCols
ordersNewCols = orders.iloc[:,[1, 3, 11, 12, 15]]

#create new dataframe - ordersToSubmit
ordersToSubmit = pd.DataFrame()

#copy columns from ordersNewCols to ordersToSubmit
ordersToSubmit = ordersNewCols.copy()
ordersToSubmit.to_csv("ordersToSubmit.csv", index=False)

#Insert empty columns where needed.
ordersToSubmit.insert(2,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(3,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(4,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(6,None'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(7,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(8,None'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(9,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(10,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(11,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(12,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(13,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(14,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(15,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(16,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(18,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(19,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(20,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(21,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(22,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(23,None,'')
ordersToSubmit.insert(27,None,'')

IndexError: index 27 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 25
````

'''

How do I expand it to not bring up the error?

CSV screenprint

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors and is much longer than needed. Could you create a [mre] that does not depend on external data? I guess this problem can be reproduced simply by creating a `pd.DataFrame()` and then inserting the columns. If you use a small example with only 3 or 4 columns, the code would be much shorter as well. See [ask], [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Without having a look at your csv file, it is hard to tell what is causing this issue.

Anyways...

From pandas.DataFrame.insert [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)

```
locint
Insertion index. Must verify 0 <= loc <= len(columns).
```

As you can see, it says loc must be between `len(columns)`, so what you are trying is illegal according to this. I think if you try to insert on an index that is less than `len(columns)`, it will shift remaining column by 1 to the right